# .NET RabbitMq declare queue throws an exception

Tags: .net-core, rabbitmq

I created a queue listener; if the user has decided to enable `UseDeadLetterExchange`, the listener is going to create two different exchanges.

1. A normal exchange with type `header`
2. A dead-letter-ex with type `header`

Here is the code for the creation of the exchanges:

```cs
var exchangeName = routerHelper.GetExchangeName(messageType);
var deadLetterExchangeName = $"{exchangeName}.dead-letter";
var routingHeader = routerHelper.GetRoutingForListener(messageType);

ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(config, nameof(config));
var queueName = routerHelper.GetQueueName(messageType, config.UseSeparateQueuesPerEvent, listenerName);
var retryQueueName = $"{queueName}.retry.queue";

try
{
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(connector.Channel, nameof(connector.Channel));
    connector.Channel.ExchangeDeclare(exchangeName, ExchangeType.Headers, config.DurableExchanges,
                            config.AutoDeleteExchanges, null);

    if (config.UseDeadLetterExchanges)
    {
        connector.Channel.ExchangeDeclare(deadLetterExchangeName, ExchangeType.Headers,
                                config.DurableExchanges, config.AutoDeleteExchanges, null);
        logger.LogDebug($"Declared new exchange {exchangeName} with dead letter {deadLetterExchangeName}.");
    }
    else
    {
        logger.LogDebug("Declared new exchange {ExchangeName} without dead letter.", exchangeName);
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    logger.LogError(e, $"Error while declaring new exchange {exchangeName}: {e.Message}.");
    throw;
}
```

Exception details:

I then create the queues. If the user has decided to enable `UseDeadLetterExchange`, I will declare a separate queue adding it to the `deadLetterExchangeName`. Unfortunately, the declaration of the new queue throws an exception in `connector.Channel.QueueDeclare(queueName, config.DurableQueues, false, config.AutoDeleteQueues, args);`

```cs
try
{
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(connector, nameof(connector));
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(connector.Channel, nameof(connector.Channel));
                        
    var args = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    if (config.UseDeadLetterExchanges)
    {
        args.Add("x-dead-letter-exchange", deadLetterExchangeName);
        args.Add("x-dead-letter-routing-key", retryQueueName);
    }

    connector.Channel.QueueDeclare(queueName, config.DurableQueues, false, config.AutoDeleteQueues, args);
                        
    var output = new QueueInfo(connector.Channel.BasicConsume(queueName, false, consumer),
                            new ConcurrentHashSet<string>());
    logger.LogDebug("Declared new queue {QueueName}.", queueName);

    return output;
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    logger.LogError(e, $"Error while declaring new queue {queueName} on exchange {exchangeName}: {e.Message}");
    throw;
}
```

Exception detail:

```
AMQP close-reason, initiated by Peer, code=406, text='PRECONDITION_FAILED - inequivalent arg 'x-dead-letter-exchange' for queue 
'C3DCD9F0168D427205B12EA4A0CC9F7457AC101BD153A619DABE8D02D186E098' in vhost '/': received 
the value 'BFC3F8133BD2AC162A56AC341B042E2A9F90D0F796B5DCF975B9DF71A00789C0.dead-letter'...', 
classId=50, methodId=10
```

What am I doing wrong here?